# capital gains tax on fungible assets in the united states (long term rate vs. short term rate)

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

I bought 1 unit of asset A in year 1
Then I bought a 1 more unit of asset A in year 2
Later in year 2 I sold 1 unit of asset A.

Asset A is fungible.

Can I use the long term capitals gains tax rate (over 1 year) to calculate what I owe?

Comment: Location is always the key to getting a good answer when asking tax questions. Plus what is the asset?

Comment: In the US there is the choice of FIFO and LIFO and the gain may be LT or ST.  If not in the US, Google for your tax rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about stocks or bonds, then the [IRS says](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/capital-gains-losses-and-sale-of-home/stocks-options-splits-traders/stocks-options-splits-traders-1) that you *must* use FIFO (i.e., the first sold are the oldest units), unless you take some action *in advance* to identify some different units sold.

Note that if the asset typically increases in value, on average this leads to the *largest* amount of taxable capital gains.